# solving a partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the following equation?
$$-f_{x}+yf_{xy}+xf_{yy} = c^{'}(x)(-f+yf_{y})$$

where $f=f(x,y)$  is a real function of two variables $x,y$ and $c=c(x)$ is a real function of $x$.

I guess one of its solutions is $f(x,y)= c(x) y$, has it other solutions?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An infinity of solutions can be derived, thanks to the separation of variables method :

[image]

Comment: Why not using latex markdown instead of an image to show your work?